# Change of University Marie Curie program

Tags: phd, advisor, funding, changing-fields, marie-curie

Hello I'm in a cofunded PhD program with the University X (This means that the University X pays half of my salary) but my suepervisor decided to quit the project and I couldn't find a supervisor inside the University or doctoral school.

So i found a supervisor in the University Z but I don't understand yet what is happening because my coordinator is asking me to apply for the University Z and I wouldn't be student in the University X although it would pay half of my salary. Is that possible??

What can I do?

Comment: How can anyone here possible tell you what to do if you yourself don't understand your own situation well enough to describe it in clear terms? You should ask your supervisor at University Z if you are unclear about what they are proposing. You can also talk to the Director of Graduate Studies at your university (or whatever equivalent position you have there).

Comment: How can anyone tell?? Is so simple, you just know how it could works or not. I'm asking if it is possible or not and what can I do.... Your answer is not helpful but thanks anyway...

Comment: As a research administrator in the US, I will just say that when we receive Marie Curies, we all groan.  It's not an experience anyone wants to have.  I would advise you to ask within your own institutions.  They are going to have terms and conditions that we don't have access to.  This program is very specific, and I would consult the administrators for help.  The other thing is that even if something is possible, the universities don't have to agree to do the administration for you.  You should consult the universities to find out what is the best course of action.